# Using sequential animation in Splash Screen using Timer and xml

Tags: android, animation, timer

I am trying to animate the splash screen using xml animation and Timer .. I want one image to come bounce and then after that another image to follow till my last image

Problem is when i am using **runOnUiThread** inside Timer following things happens :

1. one image comes animated then
2. both of them comes animated instead of only second image

**here is Splash.java**

```
public class Splash extends Activity implements AnimationListener {
    LinearLayout li ;
    ImageView s,e,c,r,e2,t;

    // Animation
    Animation animBounce;

   // protected static final int TIMER_RUNTIME = 5000; // in ms --> 10s 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash2);


    // load the animation
        animBounce = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.bounce);  


     // set animation listener
        animBounce.setAnimationListener(this);

        s=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgs);
        e=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imge);
        c=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgc);
        r=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgr);
        e2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imge2);
        t=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgt);


    //Start Animation


        TimerTask animS = new TimerTask(){public void run() {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {

                     s.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        s.startAnimation(animBounce);

                }
            });

        }
        };

        TimerTask animE = new TimerTask(){public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {

                     e2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     e2.startAnimation(animBounce);

                }
            });
        }
        };

        TimerTask animC = new TimerTask(){public void run() {
            c.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            c.startAnimation(animBounce);
        }
        };

        TimerTask animR = new TimerTask(){public void run() {
            r.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            r.startAnimation(animBounce);
        }
        };

        TimerTask animE2 = new TimerTask(){public void run() {
            e2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            e2.startAnimation(animBounce);
        }
        };

        TimerTask animT = new TimerTask(){public void run() {
            t.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            t.startAnimation(animBounce);
        }
        };

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){public void run() {
            Intent it=new Intent(Splash.this,TrippleDesDecrypt.class);
            startActivity(it);
            finish();
            }
        };

        Timer tmrS=new Timer();
        Timer tmrE=new Timer();

        tmrS.schedule(animS, 1000);
        tmrE.schedule(animE, 1900);
        //t.schedule(task, 5*1000);
       }
```

Comment: what do you need these Timers/TimerTasks for?

Comment: I need timer task because I want 2nd animation to start after the first has ended .. not simultaneously.

Comment: then use AnimationListener

Comment: Hey can you please share the bounce.xml code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys to respond here is the code which worked for me

```
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // Take any action after completing the animation

        // check for fade in animation
        if (animation == animBounce1) {
            e2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            e2.startAnimation(animBounce2);
        }
        if (animation == animBounce2) {
            c.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            c.startAnimation(animBounce3);
        }
        if (animation == animBounce3) {
            r.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            r.startAnimation(animBounce4);
        }
        if (animation == animBounce4) {
            e.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            e.startAnimation(animBounce5);
        }
        if (animation == animBounce5) {
            t.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            t.startAnimation(animBounce6);
        }
    }
```